# Error in redefinition of subclass in C++

Tags: c++, class, subclass

i get from compiler the following error:

```
uni.cpp:63:1: error: redefinition of ‘Studente::Studente()’
 Studente::Studente() : Persona(){
 ^

In file included from uni.cpp:1:0:
uni.h:34:5: note: ‘Studente::Studente()’ previously defined here
     Studente():Persona(){};
     ^

uni.cpp:68:1: error: redefinition of ‘Studente::Studente(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’
 Studente::Studente(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_,string facolta_,string corso_) : Persona(nome_,cognome_,anno_,mese_,gi
 ^

In file included from uni.cpp:1:0:
uni.h:35:5: note: ‘Studente::Studente(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, int, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’ previously defined here
     Studente(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_,string facolta_,string corso_) : Persona(nome_,cognome_,anno_,mese_,giorno_)
     ^
```

And can't find out what's wrong

The file are:

**UNI.H**

```
#ifndef _UNI_H_
#define _UNI_H_
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Persona{
  private:
    string nome;
    string cognome;
    int anno;
    int mese;
    int giorno;
  public:
    Persona();
    Persona(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_);
    void SetNome(string nome_);
    void SetCognome(string cognome_);
    void SetAnno(int anno_);
    void SetMese(int mese_);
    void SetGiorno(int giorno_);
    string GetNome();
    string GetCognome();
    int GetAnno();
    int GetMese();
    int GetGiorno();
};

class Studente : public Persona{
  private:
    string facolta;
    string corso;
  public:
    Studente():Persona(){};
    Studente(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_,string facolta_,string corso_) : Persona(nome_,cognome_,anno_,mese_,giorno_){};
    void SetFacolta(string facolta_);
    void SetCorso(string corso_);
    string GetFacolta();
    string GetCorso();
};

#endif
```

**UNI.CPP**

```
#include "uni.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Persona::Persona(){
  SetNome("");
  SetCognome("");
  SetAnno(0);
  SetMese(0);
  SetGiorno(0);
}

Persona::Persona(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_){
  SetNome(nome_);
  SetCognome(cognome_);
  SetAnno(anno_);
  SetMese(mese_);
  SetGiorno(giorno_);
}

void Persona::SetNome(string nome_){
  nome=nome_;
}

void Persona::SetCognome(string cognome_){
  cognome=cognome_;
}

void Persona::SetAnno(int anno_){
  anno=anno_;
}

void Persona::SetMese(int mese_){
  mese=mese_;
}

void Persona::SetGiorno(int giorno_){
  giorno=giorno_;
}

string Persona::GetNome(){
  return nome;
}

string Persona::GetCognome(){
  return cognome;
}

int Persona::GetAnno(){
  return anno;
}

int Persona::GetMese(){
  return mese;
}

int Persona::GetGiorno(){
  return giorno;
}


Studente::Studente() : Persona(){
  SetFacolta("");
  SetCorso("");
}

Studente::Studente(string nome_,string cognome_,int anno_,int mese_,int giorno_,string facolta_,string corso_) : Persona(nome_,cognome_,anno_,mese_,giorno_){
  SetFacolta(facolta_);
  SetCorso(corso_);
}

void Studente::SetFacolta(string facolta_){
  facolta=facolta_;
}

void Studente::SetCorso(string corso_){
  corso=corso_;
}

string Studente::GetFacolta(){
  return facolta;
}

string Studente::GetCorso(){
  return corso;
}
```

I know the main is missing... but that sure is not the problem!
It seems that the compiler tries to redefine the classes in the `uni.cpp` file.
Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_UNI_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, you're defining `Studente`'s Constructor twice.

In the header:
`Studente():Persona(){};` This should just be `Studente();`

Same with the other constructor.

Comment: Thank you all, I'm still learning and that was a dumb question!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this constructor definition in the header:

```
Studente():Persona(){};
```

replace it with a declaration, since you have a definition in the .cpp:

```
Studente();
```

Answer (score 2):

In `uni.h` in the `class Studente` you have

```
Studente():Persona(){};
```

This declares and defines a default constructor for `Studente`.  Then in `uni.cpp` you have

```
Studente::Studente() : Persona(){
  SetFacolta("");
  SetCorso("");
}
```

Which redefines the default constructor.  You need to remove one of the definitions or change

```
Studente():Persona(){};
```

to

```
Studente();
```